# Is there a clean way to get borders on a <tbody /> in pure CSS?

Tags: css

I'd like to set a background and a rounded border on a `<tbody/>`, such as

```
tbody { border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid black; background: #ccf; }
```

However, when I try this in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpIuD), the border and background color display, but the `<tbody/>` still has square corners.

I'm able to work around this problem using a series of `:last-child` and `:first-child` selectors to apply the radius to individual `td`s on the corners, as for example

```
tbody tr:first-child td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 15px; }
```

[This version does what I want](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xiaCc) (at least, under firefox) but also feels extremely verbose and hacky, a problem that'll only get worse when I add the prefixed versions for compatibility (`-moz-`, `-webkit-` etc), and support for `<th/>` elements in addition to `<td/>`. Is there a succinct, pure-css way of getting this behavior?

Comment: I had this exact issue a while back and basically came to the same working example that you did. `tbody` is kind of a weird duck when it comes to CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have collapsed the borders in the table, simply set `display:block` on the `tbody` and apply the `border-radius`.

[**Codepen example**](http://codepen.io/JoshC/pen/emJah)

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}

tbody {
    background: #ccf;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
}

th, td {
    width: 200px;
}

td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This seems to detach the column widths from those in the `<thead />`

Comment: @Dan You're right - that's a characteristic of a block level element. You would have to set a defined width. http://codepen.io/JoshC/pen/emJah

Comment: @JoshCrozier Codepen example is not working anymore