# rounding the corners of html table body

Tags: html, css, html-table, rounded-corners

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woahLcuk/)

My attempt to round the corners of a `tbody` element has been unsuccessful.

I was able to round the corners of a `tr` element in the `tbody` with the following

**CSS**

```
.tr .rounded-corners {

  height: 225px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #888888;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

However, when I try to do a similar style with `tbody` the corners are not rounded?

```
.tbody .rounded {

  background: red;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

The background does appear red.

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: Using something such as jsfiddle would be extremely helpful, and would more likely result in your question being answered.

Comment: You can't put a border on the Tbody. You have to put the border-radius on the table element. This page should give you more information: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xiaCc, found it on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756736/is-there-a-clean-way-to-get-borders-on-a-tbody-in-pure-css. It sets the borders of the bordering cells. (Not always desirable, but a work-around).

Comment: @Bubby4j Fiddle posted thanks for the hint

Comment: what is the benefit of rounding the tbody corners instead of the actual table corners? [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/woahLcuk/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your table is set to `border-collapse: separate` (the default) then the border radius may, or may not be applied to the `<tbody>`, depending on the browser; the behaviour is undefined in the specifications.

According to the specs — [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#border-radius-tables) (emphasis mine):

> The effect of border-radius on internal table elements **is undefined** in
>   CSS3 Backgrounds and Borders, but may be defined in a future
>   specification. CSS3 UAs should **ignore border-radius properties applied
>   to internal table elements** when ‘border-collapse’ is ‘collapse’.

For consistent results, based on your example, you would have to set the `tbody` to `display: block` [as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19756779/2930477). This will break the table behaviour somewhat, but could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this.,

```
.bodytable {
  background:blue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```