# How to add border-radius on <tbody> element?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to add the `border-radius` style on the `<tbody>` element.

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody style="border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 12px;">
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `border` renders correctly, unfortunately without rounding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try using `box-shadow` along with `border-radius`.

```css
tbody {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, your option works and keep the table structure.

Comment: You save my day. Thanks!

Comment: Amazingly simple solution, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that works for me :

```css
body {
  background-color: #2b7b2b;
}

table tbody {
  background-color: white;
}

table tbody td {
  display: table-cell
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>column 1</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
        <td>column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't have rounded borders. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

```css
tbody{
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead> 
      <th>head...</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td>test...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td{
    padding: 5px;
}
table tbody td{
    border: 1px solid  #19dbd0;
  text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  
  table tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
  }
  table tbody tr td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
  }
  table tbody{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #19dbd0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

```html
  <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$50</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

collapse the borders in the table

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

try adding this in the tbody style

```
display:block
```

see similar question here

[Is there a clean way to get borders on a  in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756736/is-there-a-clean-way-to-get-borders-on-a-tbody-in-pure-css)

Comment: The border now works, but I lost the table structure, so the problem still exists :(

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a separate style, such as a `<style>` tag or an external style sheet, rather than styling inline.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>header</thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td>td content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    #myTable{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }
</style>
```