# How can I round the border of my table body?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-tables

Here is my problem:
I need my table to have a) a border around **only** the table body and b) this border needs to be rounded. Their border is there, but I cannot seem to get it rounded - can anyone help?
I've tried just adding "rounded" in various places and a lot more, but nothing seems to work.

```
  <table className="w-full border-collapse text-left">
    <thead>
      <tr className="">
        <th>Display</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
        <th>Invested</th>
        <th>Development</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th className="w-10"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="border-solid rounded">
      <tr className="border-solid rounded ">
        <td className="">
          <ToggleChecked />
        </td>
        <td>My Portfolio</td>
        <td>$101.348,98</td>
        <td className="text-[#5FCD8A]">
          +3.02%
          <br />
          $50.600,05
        </td>
        <td>$120,560.34</td>
        <td className="w-10">MORE</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[image: My code so far]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a `box-shadow` to "fake" the border:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<table class="w-full border-collapse text-left">
    <thead>
      <tr class="">
        <th>Display</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
        <th>Invested</th>
        <th>Development</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th className="w-10"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="rounded shadow-[0_0_0_1px_theme(borderColor.DEFAULT)]">
      <tr class="">
        <td class="">
          <ToggleChecked />
        </td>
        <td>My Portfolio</td>
        <td>$101.348,98</td>
        <td class="text-[#5FCD8A]">
          +3.02%
          <br />
          $50.600,05
        </td>
        <td>$120,560.34</td>
        <td class="w-10">MORE</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Looks good so far - but then how would I add the borders between the rows (I actually have more than just the one)?

Comment: Add borders to the rows

Comment: It may be a minor point, but this solution is working in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a tailwind problem. It's per CSS speficification that border-radius does not work on `tbody`. You can try to simulate it somehow with some tricks like a `box-shadow` trick mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814066/2665139

Just add:

```
tbody {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

See also a similar question: [Is there a clean way to get borders on a <tbody /> in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756736/is-there-a-clean-way-to-get-borders-on-a-tbody-in-pure-css)